# Pinball in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, applet, japplet

actually I have a code which I think it's complete , but i don't know how to 
run it on Eclipse...

that's a pinball game on java and i want to practice from this code :

> http://www.cs.cityu.edu.hk/~cssamk/pinball/index.html

in all classes it shows this error :

```
**Selection Doesn't contain an applet...**
```

what should I do to run it ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<APPLET CODE="PinBallGame.class" WIDTH=556 HEIGHT=530>
    <PARA NAME="HIT_SOUND" VALUE="sounds/floor.au"> 
</APPLET>
```

That applet element combined with the [japplet](/questions/tagged/japplet) tag makes me think the class declaration of that class must be:

```
public class PinBallGame extends JApplet //..
```

However a search on 'PinBallGame.java' in the list of classes shows no hits.  I.E. whatever that code represents, it is not a complete example of the applet.

> ..want to practice from this code:

That code is a poor example to base learning on, given the lack of a complete, workable example.

More importantly, it is much easier to develop and deploy a free floating desktop application in a frame (`JFrame`).